# Use raspi to redirect wireless/bluetooth keyboard to different computers

Tags: raspbian, wireless, keyboard, bluetooth, mouse

I have around 5 computers, and having 5 keyboards is 4 too many for me right now. What I want to do is connect my Kinesis Advantage (wired) keyboard to my raspi, have the raspi redirect all incoming keystroaks to one of the 5 computers, and toggle between the selected computer via shortcuts (ie. <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> through to<kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>), observe:

[image: keyboard signal redirects]

As can be seen, I am redirecting to multiple operating systems, for this reason, and the fact that I dont want to use ssh or X11-forwarding, I want use an existing wireless/bluetooth keyboard dongle thingy like this one:

[image: Keyboard dongle]

Then have one dongle connected to each of the 5 desktops, and have my raspi wirelessly transmit all the captured keystrokes. What I don't fully understand is how to **capture** all the keystrokes and more importantly how to **transmit** them wirelesly. To complicate matters even further, I would also need to carry out the above for a [wireless] mouse.

Comment: Check out http://synergy-foss.org/ it may do what you want.

Comment: @SteveRobillard yes I already looked at that, and it is software level, which I am worried about. For example, gaming could lead to problems. This can be rememdied by locking the mouse to a screen, but it also presents other problems (ie. oversensitive mouse during gaming).

Comment: Any method of abstracting the mouse/kb will have some of these if not all of these problems especially in a gaming environment. Have you considered a KVM switch>

Comment: @SteveRobillard I remember considering KVM switches a long time ago, but then forgot about them. A KVM switch is essentially what I want, but they all look like they are from circa 1991 http://www.newegg.ca/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16817107248

Comment: if it ain't broke don't fix it. Remember how old the keyboard and mouse are.

Comment: @SteveRobillard I suppose you are right...but still those KVM's are bigger than the XBOX 360 power converter/

Comment: For five computers yes, but if you can get away with only 2 they are roughly the size of the pi (plus the cables).

Comment: Just bought this one. Lets see how it works out http://www.ebay.ca/itm/4-PORT-USB-2-0-KVM-KEYBOARD-MONITOR-VGA-SVGA-SWITCH-BOX-/180443537219?pt=US_Video_Cables_Adapters&hash=item2a0345df43&_uhb=1

Comment: For what it's worth, I'm using a 4 port KVM still. Only downside is that it uses PS2 and not USB, so I can't plug one of my computer's inputs into it as it only has USB ports haha

Comment: @Lawrence you can get a cheap ps2 to usb adapter (that connects the mouse and keyboard to a single usb port.

Comment: I've seen those, but I rarely need to actually do anything to the machine with only USB ports so I've just left it as it is. Thanks for the suggestion though ! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [Synergy](http://synergy-foss.org/). I've been using it for 4+ years daily between an Ubuntu box and a Windows one. Granted, it wasn't for gaming but I haven't noticed lag.